# How do I set the window name/title in ElectronJS?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

Silly question, but I've been struggling just trying to change an Electron window's name for a while now, so hopefully someone here can just help me with it.

I'm trying to change it from "Electron" to anything else. I can get every other title/name changed to what I want, but no matter what I seem to try, it always says "Electron"... :(

[image]

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title> <!-- Window name isn't this -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
// main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        },
        title: 'Foo' // Window name isn't this
    })
    app.setName('Bar') // Window name isn't this
    win.setTitle('ReeeeeBar') // Window name isn't this
    win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

```js
// package.json
{
  "name": "foobar-electron-app", // Window name isn't this
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.1.2"
  }
}
```

To be very specific, I'm trying to change this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you can change that particular name. But it's hacky and has no sense :).

For MacOSX, go to `node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Info.plist` and change value for `CFBundleName`.

For packaged apps electron/builder will look into `productName` or `name` field in `package.json` - no need for hacks.

Comment: Very interesting. I probably don't need to since now I'm confident the build will have it, but good to know! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, you can't change that during development.

When you build (with [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/)) it will change that to whatever the `name` field is in `package.json`.